# User will get different points depending on which try to get their question right

Tags: python

I am trying to create a score system for my game. For each of the three tries, the user will get different points for getting the question right. For example, if the user gets the question right on the first try, he or she will receive 3 points. If they get it right on the second try, they will receive two points (one point on the third try and zero points if they run out of the three tries). How would I be able to do this?

```
total_score = 0
correct_answer = 2004
print('What was the year when Arsenal last won the Premier League?')
try:
    for x in range(1, 4):
        user_guess = int(input(f'Attempt {x}. '))
        if user_guess == correct_answer:
            total_score += 1
            print(f'Good job! Your current score {total_score}')
            break
    else:
        print(f'Incorrect! {total_score}')
except(ValueError):
    print('Enter a numerical value for year.')
```

Comment: You can use the current try number in the calculation of the score: `total_score += 4 - x`

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
total_score = 0
correct_answer = 2004
MAX_POINTS = 4
print('What was the year when Arsenal last won the Premier League?')
try:
    for x in range(1, MAX_POINTS):
        user_guess = int(input(f'Attempt {x}. '))
        if user_guess == correct_answer:
            total_score += MAX_POINTS - x
            print(f'Good job! Your current score {total_score}')
            break
    else:
        print(f'Incorrect! {total_score}')
except(ValueError):
    print('Enter a numerical value for year.')
```

Answer (score 1):

MUST READ THE COMMENTS TO UNDERSTAND HOW IT WORKS..

```
total_score = 0
correct_answer = 2004
user_guess = ''   # A blank string for user response. Strings can be reassigned later.

print('What was the year when Arsenal last won the the Premier League?')

for x in range(1, 4):
    try:  # This is the actual place to use exception handling
        user_guess = int(input('Attempt ' + str(x) + ': '))
    except ValueError:
        print('You did not enter a numerical value for year.')
        break

    if user_guess == correct_answer:
        total_score += (4-x)  # will add (4-1), (4-2), (4-3) in subsequent loop runs.
        print('Good Job! Your Current score: ' + str(total_score))
        break

    else:
        print('Uh oh! You didn\'t get that right. Current score: ' + str(total_score) + '. Try Again..')

        if x == 3: # To check if the three attempts have been used or not.
            print('Alas! You are out of attempts. Try back later')
            break
        else:
            continue
```